# Symfony 3.4 EntityMerger injection in Controler

Tags: php, symfony

I have been creating web application using symfony 3.4, I want to use EntityMerger inside PATCH method in the controller.

When I inject the EntityMerger in the constructor of the controller it takes the value null in the function patchMovieAction.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
class EntityMerger
{
    private $annotationReader;
    public function __constructor(AnnotationReader $annotationReader)
    {
        $this->annotationReader = $annotationReader;
    }
    public function merge($entity, $changes): void
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

the Controller:

```
class MoviesController extends AbstractController
{
    use ControllerTrait;  
    private $entityMerger;
    public function __constructor(EntityMerger $entityMerger)
    {
        $this->entityMerger = $entityMerger;
    }

    public function patchMovieAction(Movie $movie, Movie $modifiedMovie, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
    {
    if(null ===$movie) {
        return $this->view(null,404);
    }
    if(count($validationErrors)>0){
        throw new ValidationException($validationErrors);
    }
    //Merge entities
    $this->entityMerger->merge($movie,$modifiedMovie);
    //Persist
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($movie);
    $em->flush();

    //Return
    return $movie;
    }
```

When I try to run `php bin/console debug:router`, I get the error

```
 Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\MoviesController": argument "$entityMerger" of method "__construct()" references class "AppBundle\Entity\EntityMerger" but  
   no such service exists.
```

Comment: Be aware that by default, classes inside of the src/Entity directory are skipped.  That is what the exclude line config/services.yaml is for.  Move your EntityMerger into another namespace (maybe App\Service if you cant think of anthing better) and it should work.

Comment: What namespace does `EntityMerger` belong to?

Comment: @fyrye In spite of it's name, EntityMerger is not a Doctrine class but rather an application one.  So it can go in whatever namespace the application developer decides.  App\Service is a common choice but it could be pretty much anything.  The problem in this case is that classes in App\Entity are not autowired since entities tend to make poor services.

Comment: How does your `config.yml`, resp. `services.yml` look like? Could you also update both PHP files with their namespaces? It seems that `namespace AppBundle\Entity` is missing in one of them.

Comment: @Tomáš  I haven't changed the content of services.yml and config.yml.

Comment: And what is in them?

Comment: It's curious that the diagnosis and solution provided in the first comment is being ignored.

Comment: @Cerad Maybe putting it to answer would help. Comments here are messy and it's not often clear who reacts to who.